# Finding the Nth occurrence of character in string

Tags: strings, sql, sql-server

I wrote an SQL Server function which returns the substring before the Nth occurrence of a character.

For example:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_getFirstNthSentence('.', 'hello world.It.is.raining.today', 3)
```

returns 'hello world.It.Is.' as a result.

The function I wrote looks dirty and slow so I want to optimize it. Any advice to make it clean is appreciated.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getFirstNthSentence
(
  @TargetStr VARCHAR(MAX) ,
  @SearchedStr VARCHAR(8000) ,
  @Occurrence INT
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @pos INT ,
        @counter INT ,
        @ret INT;

    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr);

    IF ( @pos = 0 )
        RETURN @SearchedStr

    SET @counter = 1;

    IF @Occurrence = 1
        SET @ret = @pos;

    ELSE
        BEGIN

            WHILE ( @counter < @Occurrence )
                BEGIN

                    IF(LEN(@SearchedStr) < @pos + 1)
                        RETURN @SearchedStr

                    SELECT  @ret = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr,
                                             @pos + 1);
                    IF(@ret = 0)
                        RETURN @SearchedStr
                    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
                    SET @pos = @ret;
                END;
        END;
    RETURN LEFT(@SearchedStr, @ret)
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to set the return string `@ret` all the time. You can first look for occurrences of `@TargetStr` with an incrementing `start_location` parameter of the `CHARINDEX` function. Only after no (new) occurrences are found, or when the required max number of occurrences are found is it time to set the return string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getFirstNthSentence
(
  @TargetStr VARCHAR(MAX) ,
  @SearchedStr VARCHAR(8000) ,
  @Occurrence INT
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @counter INT = 0
          , @index INT = 0
          , @newIndex INT
          , @end BIT = 0;

    WHILE(@end = 0 AND @counter < @occurrence)
    BEGIN
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
        SET @newIndex = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr, @index + 1);
        IF (@newIndex > 0)
            SET @index = @newIndex;
        ELSE
            SET @end = 1;
    END
    IF @index > 0 SET @index = @index - 1;
    RETURN LEFT(@SearchedStr, @index)
END
```

Note that this returns an empty string if no occurrences are found. I think that's more correct for a function that returns "everything until the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of *x*".